# How to combine logs in order?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to combine all my logs, in time and date order, in a batch script.

For example these are my files:

```
Log_20220805_1200-2340.log
Log_20220805_2340-0230.log
Log_20220806_0230-0725.log
```

In the first log I have `123`

In the second: `456`

In the last log: `789`

I want to create a new log which combines all to `All_Logs.log` and contains `123456789`(in one line) in order (with the log time help) and I want to delete all other logs

Im using Windows (CRLF)

Please help me, I'm desperate.

Comment: Wouldn't that last file be `Log_20220807_0230-0725.log` since it would be generated the next day? What have you tried?

Comment: Surely that would just be the first file, and the list posted isn't ordered, @Magoo! Dynamic, what are the line endings of the files? are they CRLF? LF? or CR? _(Windows, Unix, Mac)_. Please do not guess, open them in a decent text editor to find out.

Comment: That does not answer my question @Dynamic. Please open the files in a real text editor, not Windows `notepad.exe`, and find out what type of line endings it uses, those will affect the complexity of the answer. Please [edit] your question to include the response to my previous comment. Do not answer it in the comment section.

Comment: @Compo: I beg to differ. Times are 1200..2340, 2340..0230, 0230..0725, so the third would logically be the second day.

Comment: not at all @Magoo, nobody said that the filenames were designed to cover entire twenty four hour periods, so just because there isn't a `Log_20220806_0725-1200.log`, does not mean that `Log_20220806_0230-0725.log`, is the wrong name. that file is according to the question the first in date and time order.

Comment: Sorry my bad XD

Comment: ...hence the question.

Comment: My request is very specific @Dynamic. It is important that you open your file in your text editor and provide the information. Even notepad.exe in modern Windows, should show in its status bar, `Windows (CRLF)` or `Unix (LF)`. Your question is not showing `CR LF`, are you certain that it is `CR LF`? and not `CRLF` or `LF`?

Comment: Yes, im certain

Comment: That'll be why you've now changed it! but thanks for the update nonetheless. Can you also please clarify that you want the new file to contain one line as `123456789`, and not three lines `123`, `456` and `789`.

Comment: Try: `< NUL (for %%f in (*.log) do for /F "delims=" %%a in (%%f) do set /P "=%%a") > All_Logs.tmp  & 
 del *.log  &  ren All_Logs.tmp All_Logs.log`

Answer (score 1):

```
del combined.txt
for /f %%b in ('dir /b /od log_????????_????-????') do (
 type "%%b">>combined.txt
 ECHO del "%%b"
)
```

should generate a new file with the logs concatenated.

The `del` commands are `echo`ed for safety during testing. Delete the `echo` keyword to actually delete the file.

Revision - result in one line.

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: You would need to change the value assigned to `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.
:: I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "outfilename=all_logs.log"
SET "outline="

for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /on "%sourcedir%\log_????????_????-????.log"') do (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('type "%sourcedir%\%%b"') DO SET "outline=!outline!%%e"
 ECHO del "%sourcedir%\%%b"
)
IF DEFINED outline (>"%sourcedir%\%outfilename%" ECHO %outline%) ELSE (ECHO DEL "%sourcedir%\%outfilename%" 2^>nul)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

The `del` commands are `echo`ed for safety during testing. Delete the `echo` keyword to actually delete the file.

No idea what  `(with the log time help)` means!